# Can't exclude Data Flow Diagram from Enterprise Architect Documentation

Tags: documentation, uml, rtf, enterprise-architect, dataflow-diagram

I'm trying to generate documentation with activity diagrams in Enterprise Architect 12, but no matter what option I choose it still adds Data Flow Diagrams to report. Even when I mark every diagram type in [image: Exclude filters] the DFD is still in the report.

I had DFD MDG enabled since begining but I've noticed that in MDG Technologies window i have 2 Data Flow Diagram on list. The diffrence between them is only the location(one has "Model" second has DFD Technology.xml). I can mark only the second one.
[image: MDG Technologies]
[image: Exclude]

Comment: I don't use the RTF generator, but that sounds like a bug. Can you state your EA version? You might try upgrading or sending a bug report.

Comment: You should probably also report that as bug.

Comment: I found a soultion to fix it. I needed to set parametr MDGDgm as empty from t_diagram.StyleEX in database for every DFD diagram. The parametr looked like that before the change. MDGDgm=DFD::DataFlowDiagram;

Comment: That not a solution, that is vandalism. Now EA won't know which type of diagram this is anymore.

Comment: Geert i have "DFD::Data Flow Diagram" on exclude list(cant show screenshot atm) but as i said on begining it doesnt exclude dfd diagrams from reports.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have the DFD MDG enabled.
If so then you cannot select the DFD diagram type to be filtered.
Enable the DFD MDG and you should see the DFD diagram type appear in the Exclude filter.

In case you have the same MDG twice then there is obviously an issue. Best to remove the one stored in the model.
Easiest way to do that is to go to the Resources View, open the MDG Technologies package and right click on the DFD that is found there, and remove it.

You might need to disable both MDG's before the one in the model will show up int the resources view.

Comment: unfortunately my MDG Technologies package is empty even after disabling both MDG's :/

Comment: even after restarting EA? Maybe you need to move the DFD MDG xml from the program files folder before EA will show the DFD MDG  in the resources view. If even that doesn't work you might have to remove it from the dababase by hand.

Comment: it helped to delete one of those MDG's and now there's only one dfd in MDG Technologies but the report still generates dfd's after marking them on exclude filter. I give up :D

Comment: As a workaround, you can also mark the diagrams themselves to be excluded from documentation. That might be a quick fix depending on the number of diagrams we are talking about.

Comment: that might be a little bit time-consuming cause there's ~2500 dfd diagrams, but thanks anyway ;)

Comment: With an sql update query that would probably take less then a second :)